# Cant run eclipse using x11 forwarding

Tags: eclipse, ssh, x11

I am trying to run eclipse on a remote 64 bit ubuntu 11.04 using x11 forwarding.I have ubuntu at my client side.

My /etc/ssh/ssh_config contains at the server contains:

```
Host *

ForwardX11 yes
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

My echo `$DISPLAY` gives at the server gives:

```
localhost:10.0
```

My /etc/ssh/ssh_config at my client/local machine contains:

```
Host*
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

My echo `$DISPLAY` at client machine gives

```
:0.0
```

I logged in the system using `ssh -X username@domain` and tried to run eclipse using the command `eclipse` . But I am getting the following error.

```
(.:2646): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(.:2646): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(.:2646): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(.:2646): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(.:2646): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_display: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)'    failed

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_display_get_pointer: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)'     failed

(.:2646): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_n_monitors: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(.:2646): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_monitor_geometry: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion `GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(.:2646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_window_new: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f2542574d4e, pid=2646, tid=139798099633920
#
# JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x72d4e]  __float128+0xe
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/sparkuser/hs_err_pid2646.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Any clues what I am missing.

Please help

Comment: If a program crashes, it is never a user's fault. Submit a bug report to the Eclipse team.

Comment: Can you run other apps using X11 forwarding?

Comment: I tried running gedit. It says
    (gedit:3172): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:11.0

Comment: try with a non-gtk app, like xterm or rxvt

Comment: Trying xterm gives :
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:11.0.

Comment: have you tried `ssh -Y` instead of `-X` ?

Comment: @abhiitd.cs: I have a similar problem right now, how did you resolved it finally?

Comment: @actual - Hey. Sorry but due to time constraints, I developed the code on eclipse installed locally on the machine. I did not put effort in solving the issue.